# Decision problem for a bundle in a line bundle extension of $\dim Ext^1=1$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, vector-bundles, holomorphic-bundles

Let $E$ be a vector bundle over a nonsingular irreducible surface $X$ given by an extension
$$0 \rightarrow A \rightarrow E \rightarrow B \rightarrow 0,$$
where both $A$ and $B$ are a line bundle over $X$. Then I have known that the extension is classified by the group $Ext^1(B,A)\cong H^1(X,A\otimes B^{*})$ and the split extension $A\oplus B$ is correspondent to the zero element of $H^1(X,A\otimes B^{*})$.

Now suppose $\dim H^1(X,A\otimes B^{*})=1$. Then **my question is :**

If I had a vector bundle satisfying the same extension to $E$, say $E'$, constructed by some way and proven that it correspondent to $1\in H^1(X,A\otimes B^{*})$ but $E'\ncong E$, then can I conclude that : so $E$ is correspondent to $0\in H^1(X,A\otimes B^{*})$ and thus $E\cong A\oplus B$?

Comment: One clarifying point - when you say $E'\not\cong E$, do you mean as modules, or as extensions?

Comment: Actually I did mean as $\mathcal{O}_{x}$-modules, but I didn't know that is the significant point. Despite my question was (may) more fitted into another answer by @AG leaner, your answer was also helpful for me, too. Thank you again for your intrest.

Comment: If there are other points to conclude this problem, reply me and I will add more specific information for my case, or re-post my real problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question is yes.

$E$ and $E’$ arising from extensions of $B$ by $A$ can be isomorphic as $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules, but not isomorphic as extensions of $B$ by $A$, meaning there is $\textit{no}$ isomorphism $f:E\to E’$ making the following diagram commute.

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
0@>>>A @>>> E@>>>B@>>>0\\@.@VV{=}V @VVfV@VV{=}V@.\\
0@>>> A @>>>E’@>>>B@>>>0
\end{CD}

So I disagree with Hank’s answer.

Actually, the automorphisms $\text{Aut}(A)\times \text{Aut}(B)$ acts on the $\text{Ext}^1(B,A)$. In each orbit, the isomorphism class of $E$ is unchanged.

In particular, when both $A$ and $B$ are line bundles, $\text{Aut}(A)= \text{Aut}(B)=k^*$, so $k^*\times k^*$ acts on $\text{Ext}^1(B,A)$, with the diagonal acts trivially. So the isomorphism classes of $E$ are parameterized by $\text{Ext}^1(B,A)/k^*$. When $\dim \text{Ext}^1(B,A)=1$, there are just two orbits, with $0$ corresponding to the trivial extension and $1$ corresponding to the nontrivial extension.

A good reference for this is Friedman’s *Algebraic Surfaces and Holomorphic Vector Bundles*, p.31.

Comment: Thank you for your help. In my case, $E$ and $E'$ have the same extension by line bundles $B$ by $A$ but have different (generic) splitting type. The one is actually I want to know, and the other is not split extension that constructed by well-known method. So I thought If they are actually different(not isomorphic) as an $\mathcal{O}_{x}$-module, I can conclude that my case was the split extension.

Answer (score 1):

Not unless you're working over $\Bbb F_2$. In any abelian category, there's a bijection between isomorphism classes of extensions of $B$ by $A$ and elements of $\operatorname{Ext}^1(A,B)$ where the split extension corresponds to $0$. Knowing that $E'$ is not isomorphic as an extension to the trivial extension and that $E$ is not  isomorphic to $E'$ as an extension won't force $E$ to be the trivial extension unless $|\operatorname{Ext}^1(A,B)|=2$.

Comment: Thank you for your comment!! I Think I had a misunderstand for the relationship of group $Ext^1(B,A)$ and the extension. Here is an additional question. If I have a extension $0 \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P^1}}(-1) \rightarrow E \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P^1}}(1) \rightarrow 0$, and knowing that $E$ is a rank 2 locally free sheaf, then I can take a 2 splitting types of $E$ : $(0, 0)$ and $(1, -1)$.

Comment: In this case, couldn't I say that $(0, 0)$ is correspondent to $1\in H^0(\mathbb{P^1},\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P^1}})\cong Ext^1(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P^1}}(1),\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P^1}}(-1))$ while (1, -1) is correspondent to $0\in H^0(\mathbb{P^1},\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P^1}})$?

Comment: Depends on your identification $H^0(\Bbb P^1,\mathcal{O})\cong k$. It sort of seems like you're dancing around another question here - if that's the case, I recommend just asking it instead of nibbling around the edges.

Comment: You're right. It was not my actual problem what I obstructed, but more general situation. Anyway, it also contained in my concerning problem. Your comment is so helpful for me! Now I will post the actual question as following you advice. Thank you again.

Comment: I think the isomorphism between $E$ and $E’$ that mentioned by OP is as $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules, not as extensions of $B$ by $A$. See the answer below.

Comment: @AGlearner hmm, that was not how I read it - I guess we should ask the OP so that they can clarify.